# Can I flip the endpoints of my Likert scale?

Tags: methodology

I am using different validated scales for my survey and most of them go from negative (disagree) to positive (agree) endpoints. In order to ensure usability, I would like to keep all scales with such logic. However, I have one that is the other way around.

Would it be okay to just swap it in my survey and later reverse code my data?

Comment: "In order to ensure usability, I would like to keep all scales with such logic." How does this "ensure usability"? I don't really think it's a problem for a survey if some scales are the other way round. I have even seen (unfortunately I've forgotten where) that some recommend to *not* have all scales in the same direction, because this may support the respondents to read the individual questions more thoroughly. (Of course you may have good reasons that are specific to your survey.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s all about interpretation of coefficients. They’ll be negative vs positive, otherwise nothing changes